# Importing a series of .CSV files that contain one field while adding additional 'known' data in other fields

Tags: mysql, matlab, mysql-workbench

I've got a process that creates a csv file that contains ONE set of values that I need to import into a field in a MySQL database table.  This process creates a specific file name that identifies the values of the other fields in that table. For instance, the file name T001U020C075.csv would be broken down as follows:

```
T001 = Test 001
U020 = User 020
C075 = Channel 075
```

The file contains a single row of data separated by commas for all of the test results for that user on a specific channel and it might look something like:
12.555, 15.275, 18.333, 25.000 ... (there are hundreds, maybe thousands, of results per user, per channel).

What I'm looking to do is to import directly from the CSV file adding the field information from the file name so that it looks something like:

```
insert into results (test_no, user_id, channel_id, result) values (1, 20, 75, 12.555)
```

I've tried to use "Bulk Insert" but that seems to want to import all of the fields where each ROW is a record.  Sure, I could go into each file and convert the row to a column and add the data from the file name into the columns preceding the results but that would be a very time consuming task as there are hundreds of files that have been created and need to be imported.

I've found several "import CSV" solutions but they all assume all of the data is in the file.  Obviously, it's not...

The process that generated these files is unable to be modified (yes, I asked). Even if it could be modified, it would only provide the proper format going forward and what is needed is analysis of the historical data.  And, the new format would take significantly more space.

I'm limited to using either MATLAB or MySQL Workbench to import the data.

Any help is appreciated.
Bob

Answer (score 0):

A possible SQL approach to getting the data loaded into the table would be to run a statement like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dir/T001U020C075.csv'
INTO TABLE results 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
( result )
SET test_no    = '001'
  , user_id    = '020'
  , channel_id = '075'
```

;

We need the comma to be the line separator. We can specify some character that we are guaranteed not to tppear to be the field separator. So we get `LOAD DATA` to see a single "field" on each "line".

(If there isn't trailing comma at the end of the file, after the last value, we need to test to make sure we are getting the last value (the last "line" as we're telling LOAD DATA to look at the file.)

---

We could use user-defined variables in place of the literals, but that leaves the part about parsing the filename.  That's really ugly in SQL, but it could be done, assuming a consistent filename format...

```
-- parse filename components into user-defined variables
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.n,'T',-1),'U',1)   AS t
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.n,'U',-1),'C',1)   AS u
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(f.n,'C',-1)                          AS c
     , f.n                                                  AS n
  FROM ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( i.filename ,'/',-1),'.csv',1) AS n 
           FROM ( SELECT '/tmp/T001U020C075.csv' AS filename ) i 
       ) f
  INTO @ls_u
     , @ls_t
     , @ls_c
     , @ls_n
;
```

while we're testing, we probably want to see the result of the parsing.

```
-- for debugging/testing
SELECT @ls_t
     , @ls_u
     , @ls_c 
     , @ls_n
;
```

And then the part about running of the actual `LOAD DATA` statement. We've got to specify the filename again. We need to make sure we're using the same filename ...

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/T001U020C075.csv'
INTO TABLE results
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY ','
( result )
SET test_no    = @ls_t
  , user_id    = @ls_u
  , channel_id = @ls_c
```

;

(The client will need read permission the .csv file)

---

Unfortunately, we can't wrap this in a procedure because running `LOAD DATA` 
statement is not allowed from a stored program.

Some would correctly point out that as a workaround, we could compile/build a user-defined function (UDF) to execute an external program, and a procedure could call that. Personally, I wouldn't do it. But it is an alternative we should mention, given the constraints.